# NegativeArraySizeException adding Scatter Data to a CombinedChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I use MPAndriodChart and I want to combine multiple ScatterDataSet with one LineDataSet

```
CombinedChart chart = (CombinedChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
CombinedData chartData = new CombinedData();
ScatterData scatterData = data.getScatterData();
chartData.setData(scatterData);
chartData.setData(data.getLineData());
chart.setData(chartData);
chart.invalidate();
```

The Line just works fine but on the ScatterData I get a NegativeArraySizeException:

```
java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -10 
 at com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.Transformer.generateTransformedValuesScatter(Transformer.java:110)
 at com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.ScatterChartRenderer.drawValues(ScatterChartRenderer.java:106)
 at com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.CombinedChartRenderer.drawValues(CombinedChartRenderer.java:95)
```

What I pass in seems to be perfectly valid data:

```
[Entry, x: 5.5699 y (sum): -0.5020655, Entry, x: 4.2394395 y (sum): 0.21312527, Entry, x: 3.5619884 y (sum): 0.45908606, Entry, x: 0.64683366 y (sum): 0.13041855, Entry, x: 5.2063227 y (sum): -0.3853986, Entry, x: 4.3252435 y (sum): -0.31767017, Entry, x: 5.9881873 y (sum): 0.2213649, Entry, x: 4.0705724 y (sum): 0.28665566, Entry, x: 3.1188233 y (sum): 0.33925194, Entry, x: 4.1558833 y (sum): 0.349967, Entry, x: 5.616512 y (sum): 0.76478994, Entry, x: 3.5945375 y (sum): 0.29368117, Entry, x: 4.4086146 y (sum): 0.085573964, Entry, x: 3.894157 y (sum): 0.6461969, Entry, x: 3.2885375 y (sum): 0.9365549, Entry, x: 3.2674248 y (sum): 0.86991787, Entry, x: 6.1956058 y (sum): -0.42813104, Entry, x: 5.3698792 y (sum): -0.22390603, Entry, x: 4.403929 y (sum): 0.08022818, Entry, x: 5.3132596 y (sum): 0.022318058, Entry, x: 5.8791475 y (sum): -0.0365236, Entry, x: 2.5035682 y (sum): -0.22752166]
[Entry, x: 0.7963708 y (sum): 0.12507936, Entry, x: 1.2852284 y (sum): 0.44808355]
[Entry, x: 6.883231 y (sum): -0.15286136]
[Entry, x: 5.358568 y (sum): -0.9050642]
[Entry, x: 6.221557 y (sum): -0.87225515]
[Entry, x: 3.392378 y (sum): -0.06295807, Entry, x: 3.9897776 y (sum): 0.21555887]
[Entry, x: 1.9450009 y (sum): 0.039005354, Entry, x: 3.6542387 y (sum): 0.13659218, Entry, x: 2.7017648 y (sum): -0.532821, Entry, x: 3.6622684 y (sum): 0.6588981, Entry, x: 4.9132524 y (sum): -0.04732264]
```

Comment: Have your tried sorting your scatter data by x-value? I know of a few instances in the past where unsorted data caused issues.

Comment: @TR4Android cool, that in fact solved the issue, you could add that as an answer.

Comment: Glad that resolved the issue! Posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the time the `NegativeArraySizeException` is caused by unsorted data in the new `3.0.0-beta1` version of the MPAndroidChart library. Sorting the data should resolve the issue.

This is because the library relies on sorted data for performance optimizations and thus doesn't work properly with unsorted data.

Comment: This is not very helpful as in some cases the data cannot be sorted (for example if they shall be connected with a line in the original order)