# Keep getting java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -2, not sure why

Tags: java, android, json

I am working on an Android project. I am creating a graph and populating the graph with json content. 
 My problem is that i keep getting this error and i am not sure why. java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -2

My Log.v shows the content of the array. So it's not empty. Maybe i am missing something.

I go through the rest api and add everything to the arraylist resModelList.
In the onPostExecute, I want to add my y-axis values to this array list yVals1.
This is where i get my error. (java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -2)

If i add the values like this, I get no error.

```
yVals1 = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    yVals1.add(new Entry(1451606400, 10));
    yVals1.add(new Entry(1454284800, 20));
    yVals1.add(new Entry(1456790400, 30));
    yVals1.add(new Entry(1459468800, 50));
```

My code
Global variables

```
ArrayList<ResultModel> resModelList;
ArrayList<Entry> yVals1;
```

Parse Json

```
//getResult
public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<ResultModel>> {

    @Override
    protected List<ResultModel> doInBackground(String... params) {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie",session_name+"="+session_id);
            connection.setRequestProperty("X-CSRF-Token", token);
            //connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
            connection.connect();

            int length = connection.getContentLength();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            String line = "";
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            Log.v("TESt", " " + length);

            String finalJson = buffer.toString();
            JSONArray parentArray = new JSONArray(finalJson);
            resModelList = new ArrayList<>();

            for(int i=0; i<parentArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);
                ResultModel resModel = new ResultModel();
                resModel.setPost_date(finalObject.getString("post_date"));
                resModel.setHow_much_has_ocd(finalObject.getString("how_much_has_ocd"));
                resModelList.add(resModel);
            }
            return resModelList;

        }catch (MalformedURLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if(reader != null){
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<ResultModel> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(!resModelList.isEmpty()){
//here is where i get my errors
            yVals1 = new ArrayList<Entry>();
            for (ResultModel ocd : resModelList){
                int score =  Integer.parseInt(ocd.getHow_much_has_ocd());
                int timeStamp =  Integer.parseInt(ocd.getPost_date());
//I get these log values
                Log.v("Score: ", " " + score + " Timestamp: " + timeStamp);
                yVals1.add(new Entry(timeStamp, score));
            }
            graph();
            Log.v("Not Empty list", "");
        }else {
            Log.v("Empty list", "");
        }
    }
}
```

finalJson log.v

```
[{"post_date":"1481895820","did_you_avoid":"25","how_much_has_ocd":"81","how_would_you_rate":"82","overall_how_would":"35","were_there_any_distressing":"0","uid":"2"},{"post_date":"1481723564","did_you_avoid":"13","how_much_has_ocd":"10","how_would_you_rate":"13","overall_how_would":"16","were_there_any_distressing":"0","uid":"2"},{"post_date":"1481723488","did_you_avoid":"28","how_much_has_ocd":"56","how_would_you_rate":"75","overall_how_would":"32","were_there_any_distressing":"0","uid":"2"},{"post_date":"1481537274","did_you_avoid":"53","how_much_has_ocd":"59","how_would_you_rate":"15","overall_how_would":"71","were_there_any_distressing":"1","uid":"2"},{"post_date":"1481295470","did_you_avoid":"67","how_much_has_ocd":"64","how_would_you_rate":"66","overall_how_would":"57","were_there_any_distressing":"0","uid":"2"},{"post_date":"1481097609","did_you_avoid":"72","how_much_has_ocd":"85","how_would_you_rate":"62","overall_how_would":"64","were_there_any_distressing":"0","uid":"2"},{"post_date":"1480673252","did_you_avoid":"33","how_much_has_ocd":"69","how_would_you_rate":"84","overall_how_would":"37","were_there_any_distressing":"1","uid":"2"},
```

I am a beginner so it might just be simple mistake.
Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post the value of "finalJson" you are getting? and linenumber of exception

Comment: NegativeArraySizeException occurred in which line of your code?

Comment: I posted the finalJson log out put. I am getting all the values.

Answer (score 1):

I found the error. It was my graph library.

I am using MPAndroidChart library and you need to sort the data. My back-end was sorted desc. I had to change it to Post date (asc).

Its related to this problem.
[NegativeArraySizeException adding Scatter Data to a CombinedChart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38694119/negativearraysizeexception-adding-scatter-data-to-a-combinedchart)

I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Sadly I'm not using the same library. Thank you for the good disposition.

Comment: ASC was the keyword and saved my day. Thanks